# VSCode extension for Databricks won't connect. "Login error {}"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, databricks

Everytime I hit "Configure Databricks", I select the profile I want to use which I set up with the .databrickscfg file in my vscode workspace and has the correct URL and the correct token. I also tried connecting with Azure CLI. Both of them do not work and I get "Login error {}" in the bottom right hand of the screen. Has anyone encountered this and know a fix?

I tried both Azure CLI and authenticating with the profile. I expected to be able to connect to my databricks.

Comment: Please open the github issue: https://github.com/databricks/databricks-vscode

Comment: I do not know how to decipher this ^ @AlexOtt

Comment: go to the URL & create a new issue providing all necessary information about version of extension, operating system, etc.

Comment: Got it, just created the issue, saw that somebody else had the same issue as well. Thank you! @AlexOtt